# Where can I find data on MARTA?

Tags: data-request, usa, transportation, public-transport

Atlanta, GA has a Metro Area Rapid Transit Authority (MARTA) which has information on trains, passengers, etc. Where can I find this data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Data

- [Marta Open Data](http://opendata.itsmarta.com/)
- [Archived Marta Realtime Data](http://klingmandesign.com/marta/) *Note: File name times are in UTC not Eastern.  Also, the marta train API is particularly flaky so trains randomly disappear and reappear and/or show only a subset of upcoming stations (ie Midtown and Five Points but not North Avenue or Peachtree Center so I’d recommend making a script to clean the data before use (and sharing that script if you make it).*
- [Public Transportation Association 2016 Transit Data](http://www.apta.com/resources/statistics/Documents/Ridership/2016-q1-ridership-APTA.pdf)
- [Public Transportation Association Data Index](http://www.apta.com/resources/statistics/Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2fresources%2fstatistics%2fDocuments%2fRidership&FolderCTID=0x0120006BE9AB89F00BAE4583BADAD635F81BA6)
- [data.gov Atlanta data](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset?q=atlanta&sort=views_recent+desc&ext_location=&ext_bbox=&ext_prev_extent=-142.03125%2C8.754794702435618%2C-59.0625%2C61.77312286453146&page=1)
- [Live car traffic data](http://www.511ga.org/#a_con_ctl&u_con_ctl&msg_ctl&h_inc_ctl&l_inc_ctl&vsp_ctl&cam_ctl&g_inf_ctl&spec_ctl&zoom=7&lat=3996483.9446&lon=-9392233.53605)
- [Code for Atlanta's list of open data](https://github.com/codeforatlanta/open-data)
- [Relay Open Bike Share Data](https://relaybikeshare.socialbicycles.com/opendata)

### Developer Tools

- [Marta Developer Resources](http://www.itsmarta.com/app-developer-resources.aspx)
- [Sample Intelligent Cities API Calls](https://github.com/loren138/martaHackResources/tree/master/intelligentCities)
- [Sample Realtime STAE Calls](https://github.com/loren138/martaHackResources/tree/master/realtimeStae)

### Source (for future updates/contributions)

https://github.com/loren138/martaHackResources

Comment: Thanks! Is this a list you plan on maintaining long term?

Comment: I'm planning on maintaining it in conjunction with the MARTA hackathons and resources posted in the Code for Atlanta Marta slack channel.  I'd love others to contribute as well if they find useful data resources.

Comment: Generally the StackExchange folks like information to be in the answer rather than linked to from the answer, but the only thing that can answer this question is links. So I'm not sure how this will play out. Or even if this beta site will still be here in a year...

Comment: I agree that inline would be easier to use.  It's just harder to maintain...  I guess I could inline the current data section of the readme and link to it for updates/additional links.

Comment: Github's flavor of markdown isn't too too different from StackOverflow's, right?

Comment: I guess not, copy paste worked nearly perfectly except for the local links within the repo which I fixed.

Answer (score 4):

[MARTA's Open Data Portal](http://opendata.itsmarta.com) is probably the best place to start. It has links to documentation for MARTA's [bus](http://www.itsmarta.com/app-developer-resources.aspx) and [rail](http://www.itsmarta.com/app-developer-resources.aspx) APIs as well as data released for their quarterly hackathons. Additionally they have a [python library on github](https://github.com/itsmarta/marta-python) for accessing the APIs.

Additional transit information can be found through the [municipal.systems API](https://municipal.systems/v1/municipalities/atl-ga).

Code for Atlanta also maintains a more general [list of open data resources](https://github.com/codeforatlanta/open-data) that includes transit information.